# WordPress.org and Vanilla Forums on 1 VPS

Tags: wordpress, dns, centos, forum, vanilla-forums

I am looking at setting up a blog and a forum. I will be using WordPress.org for the blog and Vanilla Forums for the forum. I could buy two VPSs but if I can get it to work on 1 VPS then that would be better.

I would like to set it up so that mydomain.com/www.mydomain.com goes to the WordPress website and forum.mydomain.com goes to the Vanilla Forums. I will be hosting the VPS with OVH using their VPS Classic. I will probably be using CentOS on the VPS if that helps.

I have looked around but could not find an answer for using two different web servers (WordPress and Vanilla).

Sorry if this has already been asked.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress and Vanilla are not "two different web servers". They are both applications that run on a web server. As long as your server meets the minimum requirements for both, you should have no problem running them both on the same VPS:

https://github.com/vanilla/vanilla/blob/master/README.md#self-hosting-requirements
https://wordpress.org/about/requirements/

Regarding running both, each under it's own domain, you would just need to setup a virtual host for each. If your VPS has cPanel (or similar) you just need to setup an addon domain. If your VPS is unmanaged (no control panel) you can setup the virtual host manually. A quick google search should turn up plenty of results for configuring virtual hosts in apache.

Comment: How would I go about running both on the same VPS with different subdomains for each? Is there some sort of application that I need? EDIT: I see what you mean. Are you saying that they both run through Apache?

Comment: I updated my answer. Yes, they are both running under apache (apache is the web server).

Comment: Thanks, I've found a tutorial for Apache Virtual Hosts! Sorry for asking lots of questions, but would 1GB of RAM be enough for the WordPress and Vanilla or would a 2GB upgrade be beneficial?

Comment: 1GB should be enough just to run both applications, but it really depends on server load. The great thing about a VPS is that it is usually pretty simple to increase your server resources. If 1GB isn't enough, go to 2. Server Fault is a better place to find answers regarding servers: http://serverfault.com

Comment: Thanks so much for all the help. I will get 1GB and then I can upgrade in the future if the server load is too much.